# black objects when rendering scene (BI)

Tags: rendering, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

when I try to render this scene I have everything black. I've used Mineways to export the model.  I think it is a light issue because if I add a sun lamp it becomes colored, but only from the direction of the sun.  The rest is all black like nothing reflects any light. What is the correct way to have a realistic illumination in this case?

Here is the [.blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6t9a3gsifx2boey/progetto.blend?dl=0).

Edit: adding environment lights there are no shadows but light works: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxtodq863iascje/progetto2.blend?dl=0

I did a lot of tries, and seems that if I put an *ambient occlusion* or *environment lighting* in the world properties panel, it is rendered properly, but in this case I have light from everywhere and not from a sun, so no shadows are rendered.

Comment: Are you saying the render is *completely* black when you render, because that's not what I get when I render it.

Comment: you are not get completely black because I've added a sun, without it there would be no lights at all and so the rendering would be black. The issue is that even having a sun light, the light does not "bounce" from an object to another, resulting for example in trees covering the ground, that is black..

Comment: Your materials are wrong, also, even with the sunlamp. your shadows are rendering black because there in no environment lighting.

Comment: sorry, how materials are wrong? what can I do to fix them? What is wrong?

Comment: seems i fixed most of the issues: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxtodq863iascje/progetto2.blend?dl=0

Comment: I'll write it as an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scene lack environment lighting, meaning that the shadows will be black, giving your scene that odd look. Furthermore, due to the import-export your materials are not textured. What you need to do is to first, add environment lighting, and then second, add textures/better materials

[image]

Comment: did it, and it worked for everything. Now there is only the material "wrong" error, I see that the material is applied only from top side and not from every side. how can I fix that? If i increment "emit" under shadow pane (now it's 0) it become colored, is this the right way? ps: really thank you :)

Comment: You want to increase the samples...